# Application Cache html5

Tags: html, caching

I'm learning how application cache works, but I got a problem.

I created my manifest file and 'imported' it in my index.html. 
In the offline.manifest file I added:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
34567.js
```

and in my index file:

```
<html manifest="offline.manifest">
```

I'm working on localhost, but when I tried to search the script, I get nothing. 
I erased the cache too, but result is the same.

I read about creating an .htaccess file and I created it with this string: 
    AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest

But, where I'd put it?

Answer (score 0):

Apache's `.htaccess` file, which configures the web server, can be placed anywhere in the directory tree so long as you write your directive paths correctly. Based on the syntax `AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest` you'd need to keep the `.htaccess` in the same directory as the `.manifest` file here.

See [this very similar question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15235/where-do-i-create-the-file-htaccess-in-order-to-serve-my-html5-cache-manifest) via the StackExchange network.

If you are not serving the `.manifest` with the correct `text/cache-manifest` content type it will be ignored.